# "make clean" causes "make all" failure

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

When I execute this Makefile without clean, it functions OK and both the shared library and the main executable are created correctly. However, when I add the clean target, the "make all" fails. What could be the reason?

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -fPIC -Wall -Werror 
LDFLAGS = -shared  

TARGET_LIB= libnsd.so

lib: nsd.o nd.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o ${TARGET_LIB} nsd.o nd.o -lm

nd.o : nd.c nd.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) nd.c

nsd.o : nsd.c nsd.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) nsd.c

all: main.c
    $(CC) -o -I. -L. main.c  -lnsd

clean:
    rm -f libnsd.so nd.o nsd.o
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `all:` target needs to depend on the lib target, so the library is built first.

The -o argument to the compiler also needs a name for executable it should create.

```
all: lib main.c
    $(CC) -o main -I. -L. main.c  -lnsd
```

Normally you want the target name to be the file that you create, otherwise things get rebuilt when it's not needed. (the lib: target has the same issue) but as an exampe for the executable:

```
.PHONY: all
all: lib main

main: lib main.c
    $(CC) -o main -I. -L. main.c  -lnsd
```

Answer (score 2):

nos's answer is on the right track.

It only *appeared* to work before, because you happened to run make in the right order.  It won't work after a `clean` operation because, as nos points out, you have not declared all of your prerequisites.  The rule that links `main.o` must depend on the shared library target, so make knows the right order to build things.

Also, you REALLY want your targets to be the actual file you're building.  If they're something else, then make will always think they're out of date even if you haven't changed anything, and always rebuild them.

Something like this will be better:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -fPIC -Wall -Werror
CPPFLAGS = -I.
LDFLAGS = -shared  

PROGRAM = main
TARGET_LIB= libnsd.so

all: $(PROGRAM)

$(PROGRAM): main.o $(TARGET_LIB)
        $(CC) -o $@ -L. main.o  -lnsd

$(TARGET_LIB): nsd.o nd.o
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ nsd.o nd.o -lm

nd.o : nd.c nd.h
nsd.o : nsd.c nsd.h

clean:
        rm -f libnsd.so *.o
```

Comment: Oops, nos updated his answer with points I made while I was editing... sorry for dups!